# google-ml-engine custom prediction routine error responses

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a custom prediction routine in `google-ml-engine`. Works very well.

I now am doing input checking on the instance data, and want to return error responses from my predict routine.

The example: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines

Raises exceptions on input errors, etc. However, when this happens the response body always has `{'error': Prediction failed: unknown error}.` I can see the correct errors are being logged in google cloud console, but the https response is always the same `unknown error`.

**My question is:**

How to make the **Custom prediction routine** return a proper error code and error message string?

Instead of returning a prediction, I can return an error string/code in prediction -but it ends up in the prediction part of the response which seems hacky and doesn't get any of the google errors eg based on instance size.

```
root:test_deployment.py:35 {'predictions': {'error': "('Instance does not include required sensors', 'occurred at index 0')"}}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following code, I created a `_validate` function inside `predict` and use a custom `Exception` class.
Basically, I validate instances, before I call the model `predic`t method and handle the exception.
There may be some overhead to the response time when doing this validation, which you need to test for your use case.

```
requests = [
    "god this episode sucks",
    "meh, I kinda like it",
    "what were the writer thinking, omg!",
    "omg! what a twist, who would'v though :o!",
    99999
]
api = discovery.build('ml', 'v1')

parent = 'projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}'.format(PROJECT, MODEL_NAME, VERSION_NAME)
parent = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(PROJECT, MODEL_NAME)
response = api.projects().predict(body=request_data, name=parent).execute()
```

```
{'predictions': [{'Error code': 1, 'Message': 'Invalid instance type'}]}
```

Custom Prediction class:

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
import logging

from datetime import date

import tensorflow.keras as keras


class CustomModelPredictionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code, message='Error found'):        
        self.code = code 
        self.message = message # you could add more args
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.message)


def isstr(s):
    return isinstance(s, str) or isinstance(s, bytes)


def _validate(instances):
    for instance in instances:
        if not isstr(instance):
            raise CustomModelPredictionError(1, 'Invalid instance type')
    return instances


class CustomModelPrediction(object):
    def __init__(self, model, processor):    
        self._model = model
        self._processor = processor       

    def _postprocess(self, predictions):
        labels = ['negative', 'positive']
        return [
            {
                "label":labels[int(np.round(prediction))],
                "score":float(np.round(prediction, 4))
            } for prediction in predictions]

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        try:
            instances = _validate(instances)            
        except CustomModelPredictionError as c:            
            return [{"Error code": c.code, "Message": c.message}]
        else:
            preprocessed_data = self._processor.transform(instances)
            predictions =  self._model.predict(preprocessed_data)
            labels = self._postprocess(predictions)
            return labels

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):                
        model = keras.models.load_model(
          os.path.join(model_dir,'keras_saved_model.h5'))
        with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'processor_state.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            processor = pickle.load(f)    
        return cls(model, processor)
```

Complete code in [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/notebooks/samples/tensorflow/sentiment_analysis/ai_platform_sentiment_analysis.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant to you, I found a way by using google internal libraries (not sure if it would be endorsed by Google though).
AI platform custom prediction wrapping code only returns custom error message if the `Exception` thrown is a specific one from their internal library.
It might also not be super reliable as you would have very little control in case Google wants to change it.

```
class Predictor(object):
    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        # Your prediction code here
        
        # This is an internal google library, it should be available at prediction time.
        from google.cloud.ml.prediction import prediction_utils
        raise prediction_utils.PredictionError(0, "Custom error message goes here")

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        # Your logic to load the model here
```

You would get the following message in your HTTP response
`Prediction failed: Custom error message goes here`